# How do I use a third party Handwriting application as input to a web database?

Tags: android, handwriting

A client, doctor, wants an android tablet application where he can see the patient registered, use a stylus to handwrite a medical review about the patient, and the app saves the handwritten comments without converting them, to the patient's file in a web-based Clinic management system we are developing . I am starting out on android development, so any links and suggestions regarding how to go about this will be appreciated. 
Many thanks.